# Finding a particular continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)(1-f(x)) dx =\frac {1} {4}$ . How many such functions exist?
I really have no idea where to start. How do we solve it?

Comment: Maybe a good start: try integrating $f(x)(1-f(x))$ from $0$ to $1$ (So use the fundamental theorem of calculus) and set the result equal to $\frac{1}{4}$ and see what you can deduce.

Comment: Hint: $f(x)=\frac12$ is a solution. Now consider $g(x)$ such that $\int_0^1 g(x)(1-g(x)) \mathrm dx = 0$. How many $g$s are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$f(x)(1-f(x))-\frac{1}{4}=-\left(f(x)-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2.$$
Since $f$ is continuous so $f-\frac{1}{2}$ is continuous as well and we have
$$-\int_0^1\underbrace{\left(f(x)-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}_{\geq 0} \, dx =0$$